# ClickListener into BaseAdapter error

Tags: android, textview, onclicklistener, baseadapter, buttonclick

i have the seguent cose into a baseAdapter...

```
final View finalConvertView1 = convertView;
    holder.buttonEliminaDalCarrello.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        try {
                            Log.w(null, "Cliccato sull'elemento del carrello " + position);
                            SingletonCarrello singletonCarrello = SingletonCarrello.getIstance();
                            Double prezzo = singletonCarrello.listaProdotti.get(position).getQuantita()*singletonCarrello.listaProdotti.get(position).getPrezzo();
                            singletonCarrello.listaProdotti.remove(position);
                            singletonCarrello.prezzoTotale = singletonCarrello.prezzoTotale - prezzo;
                            TextView textView = (TextView) finalConvertView1.findViewById(R.id.textViewPrezzoTotale);
                            Log.w(null, "Prezzo totale del carrello: " + singletonCarrello.prezzoTotale);
                            /*FragmentCarrello fragment = new FragmentCarrello();
                            fragment.aggiornaPrezzoCarrello();
                            fragment.aggiornaListaCarrello();*/
                            textView.setText("Prezzo totale: " + singletonCarrello.prezzoTotale + euro);
                            listViewCarrello.setAdapter(new CustomListAdapterCarrello(finalConvertView1.getContext(), singletonCarrello.listaProdotti));
                        }
                        catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.w(null, "Entrato nell'eccezzione dell'onclick Carrello: "+e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });
```

When i try to run the project it find me a javaNullPointerExceptin in

```
textView.setText("Prezzo totale: " + singletonCarrello.prezzoTotale + euro);
```

can anyone explain me why? thanks in advance

Comment: Apparently `textView` is `null`.

Comment: no, euro is a string that i implement before

Answer (score 0):

this is the problem

```
singletonCarrello.prezzoTotale = singletonCarrello.prezzoTotale - prezzo;
```

it's like 3= 3-1

Comment: Like `singletonCarrello.prezzoTotale -= 1`

Comment: Huh? That's not how assignment works. a = a - 1 is totally valid.